# Why the name 'AuthConfig' does not exist in current context

Tags: c#, asp.net, dll

My Global.asax file looks like this:

```
<%@ Application Language="C#" %>
<%@ Import Namespace="WMED" %>
<%@ Import Namespace="System.Web.Optimization" %>
<%@ Import Namespace="System.Web.Routing" %>

<script runat="server">

    void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Code that runs on application startup
        BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);
        AuthConfig.RegisterOpenAuth();
        RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
    }

    void Application_End(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //  Code that runs on application shutdown

    }

    void Application_Error(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Code that runs when an unhandled error occurs

    }

</script>
```

When I first ran my web application I received the following error:

```
Compiler Error Message: CS0433: The type 'WebSite5.BundleConfig' exists in both 'c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\dc09734f\e0cd1143\App_Code.f12uuiuu.dll' and 'c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\dc09734f\e0cd1143\assembly\dl3\f6c46402\e43f8fd6_b679cf01\WMEXEC.DLL'

Source Error:

Line 9:      {
Line 10:         // Code that runs on application startup
Line 11:         BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);
Line 12:         AuthConfig.RegisterOpenAuth();
Line 13:         RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
```

I add the `batch=false` to my `Web.config` file and re-ran the web application and now I receiving the following errors:

```
Compiler Error Message: CS0103: The name 'AuthConfig' and 'RouteConfig' does not exist in the current context

Source Error:

Line 10:         // Code that runs on application startup
Line 11:         BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);
Line 12:         AuthConfig.RegisterOpenAuth();
Line 13:         RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
Line 14:     }
```

They two name in question are .CS file that is located in my App_Code folder but I am not sure why it's not working.

Please help me resolve this.

Comment: It's probably because you are importing the `WMED` namespace, can you remove it?

Comment: From the Global.ASAX file?

Comment: Yes, remove the `<%@ Import Namespace="WMED" %>` line.

Comment: I get the `CS0103: The name 'BundleConfig' does not exist in the current context` for all three lines.

Comment: Remove the `batch=false` from the `web.config` and try again.

Comment: I removed the line as you mentioned, removed the batch=false and I still get the same error :/

Comment: Which error do you get now? In the question you mention 2 different ones. Can yuo get back to the situation where you had only the first error?

Comment: You want me to put back the line and revert back to how it was before?

Comment: You say `When I first ran my web application I received the following error:` above, go back to that state and THEN remove the `WMED` reference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both AuthConfig and RouteConfig are classes generated by VS.NET as part of ASP.NET MVC Web Application project.

AuthConfig is a class for authentication with an OAuth provider: http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/security/using-oauth-providers-with-mvc

Typical RouteConfig looks as https://github.com/shanselman/ASP.NET-MVC-and-DbGeography/blob/master/SpatialFun/App_Start/RouteConfig.cs

If you convert a web site project into a web application project then you might need to select another type of project - non-MVC - ASP.NET WebForms Application. I would suggest to create a brand new webproject in VS.NET and copy all code from website there. This should fix issues with missing references or other "website"-related issues.

Comment: This isn't an answer to the question :)

Comment: I have both .CS file in my folder. Can I just comment out the two line and my web application should work fine?

Comment: I chose ASP.NET empty Web Application project when I did it so it shouldn't add anything for MVC!

Comment: Since you didn't have them in your old project I think you could exclude both .cs files from the new project and comment out AuthConfig.RegisterOpenAuth(); and RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);

Comment: I have another .CS file in the App_Code folder which is being called in my Default.aspx.cs file... `UrgentCareWaitTime urgentcare = new UrgentCareWaitTime();`. Now that is being duplicated, with this error: `Compiler Error Message: CS0433: The type 'UrgentCareWaitTime' exists in both 'c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\dc09734f\e0cd1143\App_Code.bfuzwq6h.dll' and 'c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\dc09734f\e0cd1143\assembly\dl3\f6c46402\848a6e19_c479cf01\WMEXEC.DLL'`

Comment: App_Code is a folder of a website project. A webapplication project does not need that folder. If you copied all old files like Default.aspx.cs into App_Code and additionally VS.NET created code-behind files in other folders then you will have a problem of duplicates. I'd suggest to delete App_Code completely. If you need any code from old files like Default.aspx.cs than copy the code (not a file) and paste it into the file which was created by VS.NET (and then delete App_Code)

Comment: I removed the UrgentCare file out of the App_Code folder and it's working fine now. Thanks.